# Как заставить фиксированный блок не выходить за пределы родителя

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь фиксировать блоки, что то плохо получается, вообщем есть блоки

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header"><h1>Шапка</h1></div>
        <div class="leftContainer"><h2>Левый бар</h2></div>
        <div class="content"><h3>Контент</h3></div>
        <div class="rightContainer"><h2>правый бар</h2></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

header, leftContainer И rightContainer хочу фиксировать, делаю:

```
position: fixed;
```

получается абсолютно позиционированным т.е. выходят за пределы родителя, пробовал родителю дать position:relative , чтоб не выходили, ноль результата, как сделать чтоб они не выходили за пределами родителя при position:fixed?

Вот так я делаю http://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/vhwWw/3/ пока плохо получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны такие варианты:

**Без правки верстки**

Добавьте такие свойства блокам:

```
.leftContainer{
    left: calc((100% - 500px) / 2);
}
.rightContainer{
    right: calc((100% - 500px) / 2);
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/vhwWw/4/)**
**[Посмотреть поддержку браузерами](http://htmlbook.ru/css/calc)**

**С правкой верстки**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header"><h1>Шапка</h1></div>
        <!-- Оба блока идут друг за другом -->
        <div class="leftContainer"><h2>Левый бар</h2></div>
        <div class="rightContainer"><h2>правый бар</h2></div>
        <div class="content"><h3>Контент</h3></div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

И поправить стили:

```
/* Устанавливаем позицию элемента в блоке маргинами.
 * Свойства top, right, left и bottom не используем!
 */
.leftContainer{
    margin-top: 85px;
}
.rightContainer{
    margin-left: 398px; /* Из-за границы блока, а так 400 (500 - 100) */
    margin-top: 85px;
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/vhwWw/6/)**

Comment: круто, жаль что кроссбраузерность хромает( Туда JS подключить чтоли придется

Comment: @bemulima, добавил пример с лучшей поддержкой браузерами. Но придется поправить верстку.

Comment: @VenZell, спасибо, круто помогли! ++